# How to parse the JSON Date format from the below given json data using jquery?

Tags: jquery, json

```
{
"2013\/02\/05":[                        
{"id":"84eb13cfed01764d9c401219faa56d53","colour":"#000000","category":"custom"}
],
}
```

I have used the jquery code given below.I am trying to access the date '2013/02/05' and the array elements like id ,colour and category of that date.

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
      var output = $("#changeBtn");
      $("#data").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("json_data.json",function(jd){
               var dates = jd.date;
               alert(dates);
                });
          });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object returned is an associative array so you can access the property as follows:

```
$.getJSON("json_data.json",function(jd){
               var dates = jd["2013\/02\/05"][0].colour;
               alert(dates);
 });
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/DLKfK/

On a side note, that is a pretty nasty object.  I'm not sure why it needs to assign an array to the date property.  If you have control over the object I would refactor it.  One thing you should definitely refactor is the extra common after the array since this make the JSON invalid.

```
{
    "2013/02/05": [
        {
            "id": "84eb13cfed01764d9c401219faa56d53",
            "colour": "#000000",
            "category": "custom"
        }
    ], //this comma is invalid
}
```

Comment: Thanks kevin.I am unable to access the colour object with that date format

Comment: It is an data for an event.On that particular date: the id,colour and category is being displayed in  an array

Comment: @balaji Are you sure the object is coming back as you state in your question?  I put that into the fiddle and the fiddle works.

Comment: If you log jd to the console does it show the object?  Are you testing this in IE?  That last comma after the array will break older versions of IE

Comment: /i logged to console.it doesnt retrun any object..I am trying it in the IE 9 version

Comment: Was it the comma? Glad I could help!

Comment: Thanks much.I guess some parsing isssue.Do you also know how to parse the date 2013\/02\/05 as normal date dd:mm:yyy

Comment: @balaji I use moment.js for date parsing.